# Visual Studio: How do you dock two Debug Windows Side-by-Side? (Immediate & Call Stack)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

QUESTION how do you **DOCK** two DEBUG windows **side-by-side**?

For the last year while debugging I had the Immediate Window DOCKED NEXT to the Call Stack window, both visible at the same time (as depicted by the attached image).  Then last week I lost this desired config by fat fingering an unknown sequence.

After hours of Googling and experimenting I can't for the life of me reproduce this config.  Best I can do is float them (depicted in image).  Window > Reset Window Layout didn't help.  Window > New Horizontal Tab Group seems to apply to code windows only.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Further reading: [How to: Arrange and Dock Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4y0hsax.aspx) on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have already tried this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4y0hsax.aspx ?